# How to resolve "Invariant Violation" error, related to redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was trying to do DOM testing, to check whether a dialog box is opening on button click. Then I got this error

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of >"Connect(Photos)". Either wrap the root component in a , or >explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Photos)".

I used jest and my component is connected to the redux store using

> export default connect(mapToProps)(Photos);

AccessoriesPhotos.js

```
class Photos extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            open: false,

        }
        this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    }
    handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    render (){
        return (....)
    }

    const mapToProps = (state) => {
        return {
          Search: state.Search,
          App: state.App
        }
      }


    export default connect(mapToProps)(Photos);
}
```

AccessoriesPhotos.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { Photos } from '../../../Photos/Bike/AccessoriesPhotos';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

it('Dialog box opens after click', () => {

  const openDialogButton = shallow(<Photos open="true" close="false" />);

  expect(openDialogButton.text()).toEqual('true');

  openDialogButton.find('input').simulate('change');

  expect(openDialogButton.text()).toEqual('false');
});
```

This is what I got as the result.

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of >"Connect(Photos)". Either wrap the root component in a , or >explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Photos)".strong text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Photos` component doesn't get a `store` since you are not rendering it as a child to `Provider` in your test. If you wrap it in a `Provider` for the test as well it will work as expected.

```
const openDialogButton = shallow(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Photos open="true" close="false" />
  </Provider>
);
```